# Convert jQuery generated dom nodes to dijit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, dojo

I've made a UI with a number of fields (textboxes, buttons, drop-downs and the like). I've mostly used the jQuery append function to simply place my UI elements in the DOM. Now, I need to convert those elements into Dijit widgets.

Is there any convenient way of doing this? Is simply adding an attribute for dojoType = "dijit.form.Button" enough? Also, since this UI spans over multiple files, am I going to have to use require every single time I need to use dijit?

This is a snippet of my UI code.

```
$("#generatedContent").append("<fieldset id = 'someFieldSet'><legend>Test</legend></fieldset>");

    $("#someFieldSet").append("<label for = 'fileName'>File Name</label><input id = 'fileName'></input><br/>");
    $("#someFieldset").append("<label for = 'secondFile'>Second File Name</label><input id = 'secondFile'></input><br/>");
```

Comment: So, you want to use jQuery to append Dijit widgets to your DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you have to do. First, if you want to append Dijit widget with jQuery, you could do the stuff you mentioned, for example:

```
$('#generatedContent').append('<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">My button</button>');
```

But, you also have to import the widgets you want and the parser, which parses declarative markup to dijit widgets. For example:

```
require(['dojo/parser', 'dijit/form/Button'], function(parser) {

});
```

However, the parser will not run automatically. You could configure it to run over the entire DOM when the page is loaded, but your elements are added dynamically, so this won't work either.

To run the parser, you use:

```
parser.parse('generatedContent');
```

**Important:** this solution is not the best one, because you first have to append a "template" (the button with `data-dojo-type`), and after that you run the parser to replace it with the actual widget DOM.

Dijit widgets also have an API you can use, for example:

```
require(['dijit/form/Button'], function() {
    var btn = new Button({ label: 'My button' });
    $('#generatedContent').append(btn.domNode);
});
```

This is the recommended approach and should give you a better performance. It also makes it a lot easier to add event handlers and other stuff later on.

I created a fiddle demonstrating both solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/L20fysnf/

---

About the `require()`, you add it every time you need to reference a Dijit widget. So if you have multiple files, you will probably have to add it on all of those files (unless you don't use Dijit widgets in that file).

If you need Dijit widgets at multiple places in your JavaScript file, you can wrap all code within a `require()` block, for example:

```
function fnOne() {
  require(['dijit/form/Button'], function(Button) {
    // Stuff
  });
}

function fnTwo() {
  require(['dijit/form/TextBox'], function(TextBox) {
    // Stuff
  });
}
```

is the same as:

```
require(['dijit/form/Button', 'dijit/form/TextBox'], function(Button, TextBox) {
  function fnOne() {
    // Stuff
  }

  function fnTwo() {
    // Stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: What about my custom attributes (classes and ids) ? When I parse the node, dojo makes them all vanish.

Comment: Normally classes/IDs get appended to the target widget as well. Anyways, like I said, the first approach is not recommended, and with the second approach you can easily add classes afterwards by adding the classes to the widget DOM node (like `btn.domNode` in my example).